# Advanced Contact Fields not updating repeater field in separate PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, advanced-custom-fields, calendly

I'm trying to dynamically add a new ACF repeater field value `(course_slug)` to the current user in Wordpress. The value to be added is a URL generated from a separate function.

If I use the following code on the original page using a static URL value for `course_slug` then the new value is added fine.

```
<?php $field_key = "field_61e9bb8b66765";

  $value = get_field($field_key, "user_{$current_user_id}");
  echo $value; 

$value[] = array("course_slug" => "http://www.exampleurl.com");
update_field( $field_key, $value, "user_{$current_user_id}");
  ?>
```

However if I run the code in a separate PHP file using two data values sent from the original page (as per below), then I receive a 500 error.

```
 url: 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cookable/write-course-to-user.php',data:{"userIDdata":finaluserid, "courseURLdata":tidycourseurlupdate},
 success: function(data) {
   $('#result3').html(data);

 }
});
```

#### write-course-to-user.php

```
  <?php  

$userIDfinal = isset($_REQUEST['userIDdata'])?$_REQUEST['userIDdata']:"";
$courseURLfinal = isset($_REQUEST['courseURLdata'])?$_REQUEST['courseURLdata']:"";
echo $userIDfinal;
echo $courseURLfinal;
echo "user_{$userIDfinal}";

  $field_key = "field_61e9bb8b66765";
  $value = get_field($field_key, "user_{$userIDfinal}");
  echo $value;
  $value[] = array("course_slug" => $courseURLfinal);
  update_field( $field_key, $value, "user_{$userIDfinal}");



?>
```

The three test echos in there display data as expected:

echo $userIDfinal; - displays 1

echo $courseURLfinal; - displays https://calendly.com/tjmdigital/cookable-1-week-1

echo "user_{$userIDfinal}"; displays user_1

Am I missing something daft here as to why the code will run fine in the original file but not in a linked one? Any advice hugely appreciated, thanks.

Comment: _"then I receive a 500 error"_ - and what does the error log have to say about that?

Comment: Hi @CBroe - sorry. Just found the log:

`#0 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cookable/write-course-to-user.php on line 11
[24-Jan-2022 11:11:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cookable/write-course-to-user.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cookable/write-course-to-user.php on line 10`

Comment: Hmm does this mean get_field() is not defined in this additional file? Do I need to include something else in it in order to make this gettable?

Comment: If this is a "stand-alone" script file, then you would have to require the `wp-load.php` from WP at least, otherwise it of course does not know any WP functionality in there. (But that would still rather be the wrong way of doing it; the correct one would be to register AJAX endpoints and send your requests to these, https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. As you may have noticed, I'm slightly out of my comfort zone here. I've added `require('http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-load.php');` to the beginning of the standalone file but I'm now seeing another error message: `[24-Jan-2022 12:04:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cookable/write-course-to-user.php on line 3` - could this be file permissions thing maybe?

Comment: Require via HTTP would be wrong to begin with - because that way you don't get the _code_ that file contains, but only the _output_ it creates. But you don't want the output, you want the code, so that the functions it contains are available for your own script to use afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe - I've tried to work out how to correctly incorporate wp-load.php into this standalone file but haven't yet been able to, would you be able to assist if possible? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to include it via the file system, from the location of your script file probably going up two levels via `../`. I am not sure right now whether that loads only the WP "basics" though, or also includes plugins (loading their script files, proper initialization) - you'll have to test it.